# Array from n initialized instances

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Hello everyone I have a problem solving this exercise. I created an instance from a struct and I initialized the attributes with random values.

Now I need to write a function that creates an Array with n completly initialized instances of the struct.

```
struct FluxCapacitor* createFluxCapacitor(){ // Instance of my struct
    struct FluxCapacitor *capi = malloc( sizeof(*capi) );
    capi->value = rand();
    capi->c_string = randomString();
}
```

I guess its easier said when I explain it like this:

When n would be 10 for example and I want to print the array I should have 10 random numbers and 10 random strings.

Thats how it looks now

```
struct FluxCapacitor** createFluxCapacitorArray(unsigned int n) {

struct capi **array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);

for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
 {
     array[i] = createFluxCapacitor();
 }

 };
```

And I always get this error main.c|46|error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode|

Comment: What is the difference between `struct FluxCapacitor`, `Flux` and `struct capi`?

Comment: My bad I changed the name in my code yesterday and forgot one. Looks correct now

Capi is the instance of struct FluxCapacitor

Comment: For the specific error you mention, it means that the version of C your compiler targets does not allow values to be declared inside the `for()`. I.E. declare `i` _before_ the `for` rather than as part of it

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you have no reason to build an a array of pointers pointing to structs, but you could directly build an array of structs:

```
struct FluxCapacitor* createFluxCapacitorArray(int n){ // Instance of my struct
    int i;
    struct FluxCapacitor *capi = malloc( sizeof(*capi) * n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        capi[i].value = rand();
        capi[i].c_string = randomString();
    }
    return capi;
}
```

You can then use it that way:

```
struct FluxCapacitor *capi = createFluxCapacitorArray(n);
...
free(capi);
```

with one single free for the array when done.

If you really need an array of pointers to FluxCapacitor structs, you should alloc separately the array of structs and the array of pointers:

```
struct FluxCapacitor** createFluxCapacitorArray(int n){ // Instance of my struct
    int i;
    struct FluxCapacitor *capi = malloc( sizeof(*capi) * n);
    struct FluxCapacitor **cp = malloc( sizeof(capi) * n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        capi[i].value = rand();
        capi[i].c_string = randomString();
        cp[i] = capi + i;
    }
    return cp;
}
```

That way, you still have a true array and can do pointer arithmetics on it. In addition, you have only to free 2 elements when done:

```
struct FluxCapacitor **cp = createFluxCapacitorArray(n);
...
free(cp[0]);
free(cp);
```

Comment: The question asks for an array of pointers to FluxCapacitor, not an array of FluxCapacitor. Your return type is wrong.

Comment: @JeremyP This is an array. Returning an array pointer seems needlessly complicated. Returning a pointer to pointer is incorrect. To simply return a pointer to the first element sounds like a pretty sane idea compared to those alternatives.

Comment: @JeremyP: My understanding of the goal is *Now I need to write a function that **creates an Array with n completly initialized instances** of the struct*. Above code fully answers that problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Look at the declaration of the API he has been given. It doesn't match your understanding.

Comment: @JeremyP: I've edited my post accordingly, but I really wonder what OP really wanted. Hope he'll tell us :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta It was the wording " I have a problem solving this exercise" which to me suggested he had been given the function declarations as a programming exercise. We'll see, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you create a single instance of this by invoking `createFluxCapacitor();`

and you do this in a loop `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`

and each time you create an instance, you store it in an array `struct FluxCapacitor* my_array[n];` like this `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) my_array[i] = createFluxCapacitor();`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The question has changed a bit and your code is pretty much exactly what I suggested in my original answer which I will leave here below my new answer.

The error message you are having is caused by your declaration of `i` inside the initialisation section of the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0 ; ...
//   ^^^ here
```

This is because you compiler is defaulting to an obsolete version of C. You can fix it in one of two ways:

1. Declare the variable outside the for loop

   ```
   int i;
   for (i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
   ```
2. (the better option) compile to the modern C11 standard. You don't say what the compiler is, but you can force it by adding `-std=c11` as a compiler flag Foe example

   ```
   cc -std=c11 main.c -o myprogram
   ```

---

You just loop through the elements of the array initialising each flux capacitor.

```
struct FluxCapacitor** createFluxCapacitorArray(unsigned int n)
{ //Function for the Array I want to initialize with n instance of the struct

     struct FluxCapacitor **array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);
     for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
     {
         array[i] = createFluxCapacitor();
     }
}
```

When you come to get rid of the array, you do it in reverse:

```
void freeArray(struct FluxCapacitor** array)
{
     for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
     {
         free(array[i]);
     }
     free(array);
}
```

You also need to fix the bug in `createFluxCapacitor()` (no return statement).

Comment: @Lundin No, the OP wants an array of pointers to `FluxCapacitor`. The signature of the function is `struct FluxCapacitor** createFluxCapacitorArray(unsigned int n)`

Comment: You are assuming that the function parameters/return value make sense.

Comment: @Lundin They do make sense. Especially considering doing it the OP's way allows you to reuse `createFluxCapacitor()` to initialise each element.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an opaque type so there's no need for the OP to mix allocation with initialization. If there was a `initFluxCapacitor(FluxCapacitor* fc);` function then the array could simply be created in any way the application wants: locally, VLA, dynamically etc. For example `FluxCapacitor *array = malloc( sizeof FluxCapacitor[n] ); for(i=0; i<n; i++) initFluxCapacitor( &array[i] );`

Comment: The main issue with the method described here, is that it's very slow, not only during allocation but also during data access. Since it is not a 1D array of objects, but rather a fragmented look-up table, access will be slow because data cache use is blocked by the program design itself. Why write needlessly slow code?

Comment: @Lundin How do you know it's very slow? Have you profiled it? You obsess too much about individual hardware architectures over maintainable and understandable code. Having said that, I agree that separating initialisation from allocation is a good design choice and I would certainly do it your way if I were writing the code from scratch but that is not what the OP has been given as an exercise.

Comment: Data cache is hardly "individual hardware" nowadays. The only CPUs that don't have data cache are small microcontrollers, in which cases you wouldn't be using malloc anyway. Also, pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to... hardly counts as maintainable and understandable in my book. In fact the vast majority of people who use pointer-to-pointer-to... seem to do so because 1) they don't know how 2D arrays work and/or 2) they don't know how array pointers work, and/or 3) they live in the 1980s/1990s and don't know how VLAs work. And most literature on the subject is complete garbage, unfortunately.

Comment: You are still over obsessed with hardware level micro-optimisations. It's also not pointer to pointer to pointer but pointer to pointer to struct which is pretty standard, especially in OO paradigms. `array[0]->value` really isn't much harder than `array[0].value`

Comment: It isn't a "micro-level optimization", it is basic program performance. If you have a list built with this design, of say 10000 items, it is going to be painfully slow compared to an array. The issue is that you force the program to read all your data from the fragmented heap, directly from RAM, rather than using cache memory. And of course you consume a lot of extra RAM, both for the pointers and through the heap fragmentation. And on top of that, the compiler will optimize this poorly. And for all of this blown-up performance, you gain absolutely _nothing_. Use plain arrays instead.

Comment: No, it's a micro level optimisation that nobody will notice except in situations where ultra high performance is needed like emulators and games. And you have *no idea* whether it is a big problem because you haven't measured it. You also do not know how well the compiler will optimise it because you haven't measured it.

Comment: In fact, it wouldn't surprise me if the compiled code is better for the pointer version because all that is needed is to load the pointer into an index register and offset it for each member. Whereas to access an array element you have to do some arithmetic on the index first.But who cares? Unless this is in a tight loop in a game or emulation, it is likely that we have spent more time arguing about it than will be saved through the entire lifetime of a progam that uses the faster design.

Comment: We probably come from different cultures. I work with real-time embedded systems where writing crap code is frowned upon... And it doesn't matter if this version generates better machine code, because the code creates a memory bottleneck. A direct read from RAM is some several thousand times slower than a read from pre-fetched cache. So by the time you have loaded the 10 first values or so, the array equivalent is already done processing all 10000 numbers. Also, coding working a plain array is likely more branch- and instruction cache-friendly too.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree with your characterisation but I accept that in embedded world the constraints may be different. In non embedded world where the majority of us work, it's far better to write maintainable code than code that will maybe save a microsecond here or there.Most people who work in the mainstream don't work in C. A Java array, for example, is always structured as an array of references like my answer. So most people don't even get the opportunity to apply micro-optimisations. And their code often runs perfectly fine.